# Identifying position in a 2D vector C++

Tags: c++, vector

I'm really struggling with vectors. Although I could do this in an array, I need to be able to pass my grid into a function without constant rows and columns.

```
    for (row = matrix.begin(); row != matrix.end(); ++row)
{
    for (col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); ++col)
    {
        //I need to do stuff like if (matrix[row-1][col+1] == blah)
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the functions out of `<iterator>` to find adjacent items

```
#include <iterator>

auto prev_row = std::prev(row);
auto next_row = std::next(row);
```

Similarly

```
auto prev_cell = std::prev(col);
auto next_cell = std::next(col);
```

Just be careful with your loop start and end values so that you do not go out of bounds, i.e. make sure `std::prev` does not go before `begin()` and make sure `std::next` doesn't advance you to `end()`.

Answer (score 0):

std::vector supports indexing so you don't have to use iterators. You can do something like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix; 
std::vector<int> row;
row.push_back(1);
row.push_back(2);
matrix.push_back(row);
for (int row = 0; row < matrix.size(); ++row) {
    for (int col = 0; col < matrix[row].size(); ++col) {
        std::cout << matrix[row][col] << std::endl;
    }
}
```